# Using 'this' in javascript function attached to object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

**Edit**:
The question referred to as the duplicate doesn't really answer why arrow functions shouldn't be used to access a non-lexical this. It just answers that arrow functions automatically bind this. My situation is that using an arrow function rather than a normal function cause me to lose the correct reference of this. If you need `this` outside of the current scope, use a normal function.

I've searched around for a solution to my problem with no luck. Even if I was pointed in the right direction as to what I needed to do would be awesome! My problem essentially is that `this.Favkey` is undefined here:

```js
const setFavorite = val => {
  console.log(this);
  this.Favorite = val;
  AsyncStorage.setItem(this.Favkey, JSON.stringify(val));
};
```

This function is getting assigned to a particular object like so:

```js
  for (const obj of objArray) {
    obj.Favkey = `c${obj['-id=']}`;
    obj.Favorite = await getFavorite(obj.Favkey);
    obj.SetFavorite = setFavorite;
  }
```

And then I am calling this later on a button:

```js
onPress={val => props.myObj.SetFavorite(val)}
```

In the first block of code, I want `this` to be the specific `obj` that I am attempting to enclose the function on. But `this.Favkey` in `setFavorite` is undefined. What is printed out instead on `console.log(this)` is what I think is the whole prototype of `Object`. So I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) doesn't have it's own context binding. They're not the same as a `function` expression.

Comment: The question referred to as the duplicate doesn't really answer why arrow functions shouldn't be used to access a non-lexical `this`. It just answers that arrow functions automatically bind `this`. My situation is that using an arrow function rather than a normal function cause me to lose the correct reference of `this`.

Comment: That's the whole point of arrow function and the dupe question has answers that explain every variations that you should be aware of before diving into JavaScript.

Comment: Oh sorry Emily I wasn't responding to you marking it as a duplicate. That's fine. My comment was mainly for anyone else arriving here with a similar question. My searches never pulled up that linked question so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an arrow function - it loses the binding to `this` which is what you're trying to access. Just use a normal function:

```
const setFavorite = function(val) {...};
```

Comment: Perfect! Do you have any information as to why that is?